# How to display div one by one which have same class by clicking next button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div with same class. I need to add class to the next div and remove the class for the previous div by clicking on next button

```
<ul class="tabs questiontabs">
   <li class="tab completed_que disabled"><a href="#questions1">1</a></li>
   <li class="tab completed_que disabled"><a href="#questions2">2</a></li>
   <li class="tab missedque"><a class="active" href="#questions3">3</a></li>
   <li class="tab completed_que disabled"><a href="#questions4">4</a></li>
   <li class="tab missedque"><a href="#questions5">5</a></li>
   <li class="tab completed_que disabled"><a href="#questions6">6</a></li>
   <li class="tab missedque"><a href="#questions7">7</a></li>
   <li class="tab missedque"><a href="#questions8">8</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here i have the class missed que. When i click the next button it should  goes to the next missed que div.

Answer (score 1):

```
let next = document.getElementById('next')
let tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab')

// Add active state to first tab
tabs[0].classList.add('tab--active')

next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let active = [...tabs].filter(tab => tab.classList.contains('tab--active'))
    let nextActive = active[0].nextElementSibling
    active[0].classList.remove('tab--active')
    nextActive.classList.add('tab--active')
}
```

Comment: This is almost good but active contains the array, because filter return it and in the next code your are trying to apply classList.remove on active which is not possible because it's array.
Making new variable such as `let newActive = active[0]` and then `newActive.classList.remove('tab--active')
 ` should solve the problem :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I just forgot it on those second calls. Thanks, nice call! :)

Comment: Cool, and one more thing that you maybe forgot is notice if there are no initial `tab--active` class on DOM Element, active would be empty and nextActive would return error that active is undefined.So author od code should give first element initial class, or do it by JS :)

Comment: I totally agree. I honestly just assumed that would be the case...is that assuming too much? I never know. I'll add a note.

Comment: Your anser is totally fine, I'm just pointing on that because sometimes some folk that don't know JS really would find this asnwer, try to c/p everything and see it won't work, and probably give downvote to you for no reason :) It's just good to note it, to prevent no-reason downvotes and give better explanation :)